# Write a function that changes circle attriubutes

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have some circles for a scatterplot:

```
baseGroup.selectAll("circle")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr({
                    "cx": function(d) {return xScaleScatter(d.xAxis2013);},  
                    "cy": function(d) {return yScaleScatter(d.yAxis2013)},  
                    "r": function(d) {return rScaleScatter(d.radius2013)},
                    "class": "circle"
                })
```

When I click a button I want the circle's cx, cy, and r attributes to change with a new set of data
using this function:

```
function reDrawCircles(theXaxis, theYaxis, theRadius){
       d3.selectAll("circle").attr({
                    "cx": function(d) {return xScaleScatter(theXaxis);},  
                    "cy": function(d) {return yScaleScatter(theYaxis)},  
                    "r": function(d) {return rScaleScatter(theRadius)}
       })
}
```

Here is my click event which calls the reDrawCircles function and passes the paramaters (new data set) as a string. I'm not sure if its fact that these are strings is the reason for the function not to work, however if the parameters don't have quotes then they are expected to be variables, which I don't want either.  Is there a better way to write this function?

```
$(".2014button").click(function(){
    reDrawCircles("d.xAxis2014", "d.yAxis2014", "d.radius2014");})
```

Comment: The arguments of that function should be _names_ of the properties (strings) - i.e., just 'xAxis2014', 'yAxis2014' etc. Then you can use it within `cx`, `cy` functions etc. with bracket notation (`return xScaleScatter(d[xAxisName])`).

Comment: Are you getting an error message? Try setting `var circles = baseGroup.selectAll("circle")...`. Then in `reDrawCircles` you can just call `circles.attr(...)` and you will have access to the data bound to the circles.

Answer (score 0):

If the 2014 values are in the same dataset as the 2013 values, you shouldn't need to pass them in to your click handler at all. That data is already bound to the circles. Instead, you could do this:

```
$('.2014button').click(function() {
  d3.selectAll('circle')
    .attr({
      "cx": function(d) {return xScaleScatter(d.xAxis2014);},  
      "cy": function(d) {return yScaleScatter(d.yAxis2014);},  
      "r": function(d) {return rScaleScatter(d.radius2014);}
    });
});
```